# Offlineimap unknown SSL protocol error

Tags: osx, email, python, certificates, imap

I am using `offlineimap` to fetch mail from several IMAP servers. This used to work but today `offlineimap` has been unable to fetch mail, producing the following errors:

```
*** Processing account example
 Establishing connection to imap.gmail.com:993
 ERROR: Unknown SSL protocol connecting to host 'imap.gmail.com' for
 repository '<redacted>'. OpenSSL responded:
 [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
*** Finished account 'example' in 0:00
```

Relevant parts of my configuration are:

```
[Account example]
localrepository  =  local-example
remoterepository = remote-example

[Repository local-example]
type = Maildir
localfolders = ~/mail/example

[Repository remote-example]
maxconnections = 1
type = Gmail
remotehost = imap.gmail.com
remoteuser = example@gmail.com
remotepasseval = get_keychain_pass(account="example@sexpression.org.uk",
                                   server="imap.gmail.com")
ssl = yes
sslcacertfile = /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/dummycert.pem
```

The `sslcacertfile` configuration was created in response to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24694579/1131145). The `get_keychain_pass` function is from [this offlineimap configuation](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/the-homely-mutt/#retrieving-passwords).

I am using `offlineimap` 6.5.7 built with Homebrew on OS X 10.10.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem started when I installed Homebrew's version of python rather than the Apple version. The error was resolved by running

```
brew uninstall python
```

I discovered this was the solution by reading about [a similar error](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/890#issuecomment-71753627) produced by another Python program on OS X.

Comment: this was correct for me too

Answer (score 1):

I have a need for both the Apple and Homebrew versions of Python installed. Some packages I need to install from pip, and I do not have administrative access to this work-issued Macbook Pro.  Thus the only pip I have available to me is for Homebrew.  What I ended up doing is set the following PYTHONPATH before launching the offlineimap.py script:

```
PYTHONPATH="/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages" exec "/Users/tblancher/homebrew/Cellar/offlineimap/7.0.7/libexec/offlineimap.py" "$@"
```

I also modified the offlineimap.py script itself.  I changed the first line, from this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

To this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Apparently env was picking up that it was in Homebrew, and therefore trying to use the Homebrew python.  Offlineimap now works correctly, and so does my Homebrew-pip-installed Python package (mutt-ics, if you're curious).